# Force iOS orientation to landscape on one modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, modalviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a universal application that supports both iPad and iPhone. On the iPad I support all orientations and on the iPhone, only Portrait.

I want one view controller (which is displayed modally), when running on the iPhone, to be displayed in any orientation that the device is in. I have seen many tutorials and SO posts that suggest using the `-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` app delegate method and this seems to work absolutely fine in respect to rotating the modal view controller. However, when I dismiss the modal view whilst in landscape, the entire app remains landscape.

Ideally, as soon as the modal view is dismissed the app should go back into portrait mode.

After investigation, it appears that the `-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` callback is not called after dismissing the view controller and I can't figure out why.

I have had a play with the example app [here](http://swiftiostutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Simple_Player_ObjC.zip), and the callback is fired when dismissing the view controller, which I can't figure out as to why. The only difference I can see is that my view hierarchy is a lot more complex and that I'm displaying a Navigation Controller rather than an explicit view controller but I don't see how that should affect the callback.

Any ideas as to finding a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use this method (working in app store build):

```c
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)
                               withObject:(__bridge id)((void*)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)];
```

Comment: Thanks, works just as well as the workaround suggested by @Igor.Mursa.

Answer (score 0):

In appdelegate:

```
  - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window 
{
// Get topmost/visible view controller
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self topViewController];

//Hire check your needed device ore other things you need
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
    { 
     //device is iphone
         if ([currentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(canRotate)]) 
         {
            // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
         }
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }  
    else
    //device Ipad
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;  
}

}
- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
    UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
} else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
} else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
    UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
} else {
    return rootViewController;
}
}
```

in the needed view to rotate make sure to implement

```
  - (void)canRotate { }
```

This will allow you to rotate only the view you want for iPhone device.

I got this code with the help of an old stackoverflow post but i can`t find the link to it now

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have just tried this, but the same issue is present. I am able to rotate the view, but if I dismiss the modal while in landscape, the app doesn't go back to being portrait. It appears for some reason my app isn't calling the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` method after dismissing the modal. Have you had this issue?

Comment: a did had this kind of problem, the only solution i found at the time was to rotate the view programmatically before dismissing it, something like this   `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:^{
        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait duration:1];}];` , im not 100% sure if this code will work, i wrote it now, my case - i was presenting a navigation controller, and i was rotating before presenting

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` has been deprecated in iOS 8, so i can't use that. I could always fire off a notification when the modal view is dismissed and manually call the app delegate method. Not the cleanest of approaches. I'll see if there are any other suggestions or workarounds before using this approach.

Comment: `NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"]; ` how about trying to set it like this